# MySQL Error 1136:Column count does not match value count at row 1?

Tags: mysql-workbench

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS actores(
    id_actor INT NOT NULL,
    nombre VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    nacionalidad VARCHAR(45),
    nombre_personaje VARCHAR(45),
    PRIMARY KEY(id_actor)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
INSERT INTO actores (nombre, nacionalidad)
VALUES ('Will smith' 'Americano');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a comma separating the values you want to insert.

```
VALUES ('Will smith', 'Americano');
```

You should change the definition for the field `id_actor` too to use auto-increment. Otherwise, you will need to specify an id for every insertion.

```
ALTER TABLE `actores` 
CHANGE COLUMN `id_actor` `id_actor` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ;
```

Comment: Ok, add it but now I get the error 1364 Field "id_actor" doesn't have a default value

Comment: That's because the `id_actor` is not an auto-incremented column, so you will always need to inform the id when inserting, like `VALUES(1, 'Will Smith', 'Americano')`. I updated my answer with the command that will change `id_actor` to use auto-increment.